# How can I compare a value from List<string> to Project.Models.Class?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, model-view-controller

> I want to retrieve data from Project.Models.transaction_details by using linq, comparing value from list of string (List).

**here is my code**

```
List<transaction_details> transactions = new List<transaction_details>();
List<string> date_list = new List<string>();
// date_list  output is ["2020-01-01","2020-01-02",2020-01-03",...,"2020-01-31"]

         while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    transactions.Add(new transaction_details
                    {
                            ID = sdr.GetInt32("ID"),
                            Transdate = sdr.GetDateTime("Transdate"),
                            Debit = sdr.GetDecimal("Debit"),
                            TransactionName =sdr.GetString("TransactionName"),
                            BranchID = sdr.GetString("BranchID")
                    });
                }
 var array1Index = date_list.Select((i, index) => new { Index = index, i = i }).ToList();
 List<transaction_details> arrayresult = new List<transaction_details>();



                var query1 = from a in array1Index
                             select transactions.Contains(a.i) == true ? a.i : "";

                arrayresult = query1.ToList();
                arrayresult.ForEach(x => {
                    Console.Write(x + " ");
                });
```

> My problem is (a.i) is an error.
> Cannot convert 'string' to 'Project.Models.transaction_details'.

Comment: which line is the error point to?

Comment: @Minasploit select transactions.Contains(a.i) == true ? a.i : "";

Comment: @Minasploit I want to compare transactions.Transdate to date_list value.

Comment: In this line transactions.Contains(a.i) you are comparing a transation with a.i. The var a.i is a string hence the error saying you're trying to compare a transaction with a string

Comment: @Minasploit yah. how to fix that ?

Comment: please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63224804/5262734

Comment: @Minasploit I have an error posted in the comment on that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably mean to check the transaction date. try this:

```
var query1 = from a in array1Index
    select transactions.Any(t => t.Transdate == a.i) == true ? a.i : "";
```

**EDIT:**
if you want a list of transactions try this:

```
var query1 = from t in transactions
             where array1Index.Any(a => a.i == t.Transdate)
             select t;
```

Comment: var query1 = from a in array1Index
    select transactions.Any(t => t.Transdate == a.i) ? a.i : ""; // this would also work I presume

Comment: yes, it would. I just copied the code from the question

Comment: arrayresult = query1.ToList(); cannot convert System.Collections.Generic.List<string> to System.Collections.Generic.List<transaction_details>.: error

Comment: see my edit. are you trying to get a list of all transactions on certain dates?

Comment: a query body must end with a select clause or a group clause.

Comment: @EfraimNewman yah. if it exist. if not. it should be 0

Answer (score 0):

```
var query1 = from t in transactions
         where array1Index.Any(a => a.i == t.Transdate);
```

try this

Comment: a query body must end with a select clause or a group clause.

Comment: var query1 = from a in array1Index
    select transactions.Any(t => t.Transdate == a.i);

Comment: var query1 = from a in array1Index select transactions.Any(t => t.Transdate.ToString() == a.i);

Comment: arrayresult = query1.ToList(); cannot convert System.Collections.Generic.List<string> to System.Collections.Generic.List<transaction_details>.: error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63224804/5262734 view his edit